# Sublime Text 2 creating custom colors for specific file

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using a text file to create notes and was wondering if there is anyway I can somehow add custom colors to certain lines just on the file itself, not associated  with the file type.

For example, somehow set that every time a line starts with # everything on that line will be red.

Comment: This is not possible without either making a custom plugin or a custom language definition, which I detail in the answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo, added a comment in the answer you linked.